# Why can't use Ubuntu to boot my PC on newer USB drives

Tags: iso

I have an old USB which I installed the Ubuntu via Rufus + the ISO file  downloaded. I was able to use it to  again boot up my old PC and got to tinker around with Ubuntu

Then the USB got lost and I bought a new one. I use Rufus to install the Ubuntu software using the same ISO file. As I tried to boot it up on the PC, I got the error, "Failed to load ldlinux.c32". I've tried the solutions online like downloading/reinstalling the Ubuntu ISO again but still keep running into the error.

Luckily somebody in the house found the old USB. I gave it a try and was able to boot the PC. I'd like to make some more copies of the Ubuntu software, but now I'm hesitant to boot from new USBs.

How do I get to boot my PC on new USB drives?

My PC is on 64 bit operating system, X-64 based processor. The ISO that I installed on the old USB is ubuntu-16.04.3-desktop-amd64.iso. This is what I'm using to boot my PC.

I initially installed ubuntu-20.04-desktop-amd64.iso on the new USB. When I try to boot, I got the error. I tried to install ubuntu-16.04.3-desktop-amd64.iso on the new USB, with the same error results

Comment: You haven't said what release of Ubuntu you're asking about, but did you verify your ISO was written correctly to the thumb-drive/media?  If you can't do it on that box, try another box (if it fails there, the write was likely faulty..).  You didn't provide release details, so I won't provide URL for how to do it (*link varies on release*).

Comment: The ISO file that I installed on the old USB is ubuntu-16.04.3-desktop-amd64.iso. This is what I'm using to boot my PC. I first tried ubuntu-20.04-desktop-amd64.iso on the new USB. After getting the error, I tried ubuntu-16.04.3-desktop-amd64.iso on the new USB. This also gets me the error.